# Autohotkey: Define a hotkey and passthrough it to system dynamically, how to?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm facing a somewhat hard question. Look at this script:

```
; Using Autohotkey 1.1.36.2

F2:: 
send_f2_withcond()
{
    if(WinExist("ahk_class Notepad"))
    {
        ControlSend Edit1, % A_Now "`r", % "ahk_class Notepad"
    }
    else
    {
        ; I hope F2 can do its original action. How to?
        
        Send {$F2} ; ??? No effect!
    }
}
```

My purpose:

- If there is Notepad running, F2 will send some text to Notepad.
- If Notepad is not running, I hope F2 can do it original action, for example, pressing F2 in an Explorer window will start renaming current highlighted file.

Writing `Send {F2}` is not correct, because it will trigger my own `F2:: ...` action recursively.

The doc says adding a `$` prefix will suppress recursive calling, BUT, `Send {$F2}` takes no effect(as if I totally omit this `Send`), the current active application receives only F2's WM_KEYUP, no WM_KEYDOWN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [$ prefix](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar) is used only in hotkey definitions. It forces the keyboard hook to be used, which is designed to filter out keys sent by AutoHotkey scripts.

```
$F2:: send_f2_withcond()

send_f2_withcond() {
    if WinExist("ahk_class Notepad")
        ControlSend, Edit1, % A_Now "`r", % "ahk_class Notepad"
    else   
        Send {F2}
}
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I am expecting. I misunderstood the doc.

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly simplify this script by using [#IfWinExist](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_IfWinActive.htm).

```
#IfWinExist, ahk_class Notepad
F2::ControlSend Edit1, % A_Now "`r", % "ahk_class Notepad"
#IfWinExist
```

Comment: Thanks. But the key point of my question is how to do delayed "passthrough" of a hotkey. Whether to passthrough a hotkey, may be determined by very complex runtime conditions.